# Unable to change the theme of the app

Tags: android

I am unable to change the theme of this app. I am using ZbarScanner library. I have added

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

But still it shows the below image. Phone is running 4.1.2
[image]

Comment: Can you post what is inside the theme `AppTheme`? What style attributes have you defined ?

Comment: Nothing. I have copied the normal styles.xml we get when we start new android project and pasted in this imported code. Actually when I dont define the @style in manifest it shows up in different theme which is classic samsung them(found in samsung apps as clock).

Comment: I am not clear what you want at the end? Different theme or differen Views in the activity? Can you please elaborate?